# How can we add action to segmented control(Which is having 4 segments shown in the image)in storyboard

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

In my app am using story board in which am using segmented control with 4 segments with 4 different actions.
When we click on the segments view is moving to next screen but from last screen it is not moving to previous screen while assigning the button action as push or modal.

[Image shows the flow of the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPw1Q.png)

How can we do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [official docs:](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html)

```
[segmentedControl addTarget:self
                     action:@selector(segmentedControlValueChanged:)
           forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```